# Calculating variance of a sum

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value

The number of students per day has the distribution N ∼ Poisson(10). 
The students of CSUEB withdraw money from a cash machine according to the following probability function (X):

X        | 50 | 100 | 200

P(X = x) | 0.3| 0.5 | 0.2

Let $T_N = X_1 +X_2 +···+X_N$ be the total amount of money withdrawn in a day, where each $X_i$ has the probability function in the table, and $X_1,X_2,...$ are independent of each other and of N. Here $T_N$ is a randomly stopped sum, stopped by the random number of N customers.

Find $Var(T_N)$.

**Attempt:**

I've found E[X] = 105 and Var[X] = 2725

My attempt at solving this is:

$Var[T_N | N] = Var[X_1] + \cdot\cdot\cdot+Var[X_N] = 2725N = 27250$

I thought this was pretty straight forward but I'm not too confident. Is it correct to make the assumption that $Var[T_N] = 2725N$?

**Update:**

If I use the property

$V[X] = V[E[X|Y]]+E[V[X|Y]$

and

$E[T_N|N] = 105N$, $V[T_N|N] = 2725N$, $V[N] = 10$, $E[N] = 10$

then,

$V[T_N] = V[105N] + E[2725N] = 105^2N + 2725N = 137500$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

The variability in $T_N$ arises not only due to $X_i$ bit also due to random number of summands $N$.

**Hint:**
To calculate the required quantities, use the [law of iterated expectations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) which results in following identities:

\begin{align}
E(X) &= E(E(X\mid Y))
\\V(X) &= V(E(X\mid Y)) + E(V(X\mid Y))
\end{align}

**Note:**
What you have calculated is in fact $V(T_N\mid N)$.

Comment: I've updated my question using the properties you've provided. It is very close to the simulation of the variance that I've done in R. Thank you.

Comment: @ThrmsNPrfs My pleasure